# Object Keys to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

The challenge asks us to create an array from a given object's keys (without using `Objects.keys`).

Here is my code:

```
 function getAllKeys(object){ 
   var array = []; 
   for(var key in object){
   array.push(key);
   return array;     
    } 
      } 

  var myObj={   
  name:"bellamy",  
  age:25 }; 

  getAllKeys(myObj);
```

For some reason it's only returning the first key

```
[ 'name' ]
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm sure it's a simple fix, just one I'm not aware of as an extreme novice.

Comment: Remove the `return` keyword from the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `return` outside of your loop:

```
function getAllKeys(object){ 
   var array = []; 
   for(var key in object){
       array.push(key);
   } 
   return array;   
 } 

 var myObj = {   
    name:"bellamy",  
    age:25 
 }; 

 getAllKeys(myObj);
```

This is because your function will immediately return when it first encounters `return`, which in your example is in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: I figured it had something to do with the loop. Thanks!

Comment: No problem--I am glad to help. If my answer solved your problem, please feel free to mark it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from gray to green.